# TWTweetComposeViewController deprecated in IOS6

Tags: objective-c, ios, twitter, ios6

My code is working as expected just that I need to get rid of this warning message.
TWTeetComposeViewController deprecated in IOS6. Any replacement for this built-in view controller in ios6?

Here is my sample code.

```
if ([TWTweetComposeViewController canSendTweet]) {
    // Initialize Tweet Compose View Controller
    TWTweetComposeViewController *vc = [[TWTweetComposeViewController alloc] init];
    // Settin The Initial Text
    [vc setInitialText:@"This tweet was sent using the new Twitter framework available in iOS 5."];
    // Adding an Image
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"sample.jpg"];
    [vc addImage:image];
    // Adding a URL
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://mobile.tutsplus.com"];
    [vc addURL:url];
    // Setting a Completing Handler
    [vc setCompletionHandler:^(TWTweetComposeViewControllerResult result) {
        [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    }];
    // Display Tweet Compose View Controller Modally
    [self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:nil];
} else {
    // Show Alert View When The Application Cannot Send Tweets
    NSString *message = @"The application cannot send a tweet at the moment. This is because it cannot reach Twitter or you don't have a Twitter account associated with this device.";
    UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Oops" message:message delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Dismiss" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alertView show];
}
```

Comment: Where did you see that TWTeetComposeViewController ?? http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Twitter/Reference/TWTweetSheetViewControllerClassRef/Reference/Reference.html

Answer (score 68, accepted):

There're some change with using Social network between iOS 5 & iOS 6.

1. About library: in iOS 6 we use Social framework instead of Twitter
    Framework.

2. We use SLComposeViewController instead of TWTweetComposeViewController.

3.Please compare some api with the following code:

```
if([SLComposeViewController isAvailableForServiceType:SLServiceTypeTwitter]) {

        SLComposeViewController *controller = [SLComposeViewController composeViewControllerForServiceType:SLServiceTypeTwitter];

        SLComposeViewControllerCompletionHandler myBlock = ^(SLComposeViewControllerResult result){
            if (result == SLComposeViewControllerResultCancelled) {

                NSLog(@"Cancelled");

            } else

            {
                NSLog(@"Done");
            }

            [controller dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:Nil];
        };
        controller.completionHandler =myBlock;

        //Adding the Text to the facebook post value from iOS
        [controller setInitialText:@"Test Post from mobile.safilsunny.com"];

        //Adding the URL to the facebook post value from iOS

        [controller addURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.mobile.safilsunny.com"]];

        //Adding the Image to the facebook post value from iOS

        [controller addImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"fb.png"]];

        [self presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:Nil];

    }
    else{
        NSLog(@"UnAvailable");
    }
```

There's just a little differences, but they're more great.

PREFERENCES:
- safilsunny Tips: http://www.mobile.safilsunny.com/integrating-facebook-ios-6/

Thanks,

Answer (score 27):

Yes, you're supposed to use the [Social Framework](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Social/Reference/Social_Framework/_index.html) on iOS 6. This is thanks to the Facebook integration now present on iOS. You will be able to use Twitter and Facebook from there.