# Attach a picture to twitter post

Tags: iphone, ios, twitter, file-sharing

How can I attach a picture to a **twitter** post like the iPhone built in photo app does?
If any body has some **samplecode** that will be a great help.
Thanks.

Comment: :[tweetViewController addImage:img];

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The other answers are suggesting `TWTweetComposeViewController`, however you should if you can avoid using this class, it's now deprecated in iOS 6,

Please see here: [TWTweetComposeViewController deprecated in IOS6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12681357/twtweetcomposeviewcontroller-deprecated-in-ios6)

And from Apple themselves, [WWDC 2012, session 306 presentation PDF](http://adcdownload.apple.com//wwdc_2012/wwdc_2012_session_pdfs/session_306__integrating_with_facebook_twitter_and_sina_weibo.pdf):

> Twitter Framework
>
> • Twitter framework is deprecated
>
> • Do not use TWTweetComposeViewController

To use Twitter now you should use the `SLComposeViewController` class of the `Social` framework, it's usage is almost identical to `TWTweetComposeViewController`.

You may need to support iOS 5, in which case you have no other option then to use the `TWTweetComposeViewController` class, but you should make the effort to check for `SLComposeViewController` and use that if it's available, simply because this will save you time and effort in the near future when support for iOS 5 is dropped, the `TWTweetComposeViewController` class really may be gone. If you rely on the Twitter framework now for simplicity as it does work on iOS 5 and 6, you're being short sighted and you **will** have problems sometime later, it's only a few more lines to do this and it will mean you won't need to worry about future iOS SDK releases.

You should import `Twitter.framework` and `Social.framework`, mark them both as **optional** imports (not required).

Example code:

```
UIImage *myImage = [...]; // an image

if( NSClassFromString(@"SLComposeViewController") ){
    // We have the Social framework in our iOS system
    // iOS 6 and later will use this

    if([SLComposeViewController isAvailableForServiceType:SLServiceTypeTwitter]){
        SLComposeViewController *twitterCompose = [SLComposeViewController composeViewControllerForServiceType:SLServiceTypeTwitter];

        [twitterCompose addImage:myImage]; // Adding your UIImage

        twitterCompose.completionHandler = ^(SLComposeViewControllerResult result){
            // Handle result, dismiss view controller
            [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES 
                                     completion:nil];
        };

        [self presentViewController:twitterCompose
                           animated:YES
                         completion:nil];
    }else{
        // the user does not have Twitter set up
    }
}else if( NSClassFromString(@"TWTweetComposeViewController") ){
    // We don't have the Social framework, work with the Twitter framework
    // iOS 5 only will use this

    if( [TWTweetComposeViewController canSendTweet] ){
        TWTweetComposeViewController *twitterCompose = [[TWTweetComposeViewController alloc] init];

        [twitterCompose addImage:myImage];

        twitterCompose.completionHandler = ^(TWTweetComposeViewControllerResult result){
            // Handle result, dismiss view controller
            [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES 
                                     completion:nil];
        };
        [self presentViewController:twitterCompose
                           animated:YES
                         completion:nil];
    }else{
        // the user hasn't go Twitter set up on their device.
    }
}else{
    // Wow you're going retro with this app, 
    // you must be on iOS 4 if you ever get here...
}
```

Comment: So what Frameworks do I need to add to my project and where: in the header or implementation file ?. Do I need to add twitter ,social,accounts and security Frameworks all of them or twitter is good enough ? Thanks.

Comment: Just `Social.framework`, go to your project, to the target, then Build phases, open up Link Binary With Libraries, click on the + button and search `Social.framework`. then in your view controller make sure to import: `#import <Social/Social.h>`, you can do this in the header or the implementation. You don't need Account framework, and you could add Twitter framework if you need to support iOS 5

Comment: But i got an error message for (twitterCompose) says : No visible @interface for'SLComposerViewController' declares the selector 'setImage:'

Comment: my bad... it's `addImage:` not `setImage:`, sorry :)

Comment: Now it works but why do you think the cancel button not working unless I tap it twice ?

Comment: Is there any other methods do I need to add to my viewController to show send and cancel the twitter view? Thanks again for your help.

Comment: No sorry in the completion block you should add dismiss view controller.

Comment: Can you please tell me : How can I make it works for both iOS 5 and iOS 6 ? because when i tried to run the above code in the simulator 5 my app crashes.

Comment: I think it is crashing because of adding the Social Framework .And I don't know how to get out of this problem.Any help will be appreciated .

Comment: Yes. On iOS 5 you any use this class. You need TWTweetComposeViewController. But you should do so with my code. Because now the Twitter framework is going to be discontinued. It will not work with newer iOS versions. So don't use it now. Although it will work ok on 5 and 6

Comment: I've updated my answer to address all your concerns with working code and extra explanations.

Comment: I think as I said the problem with the Social Framework so that means I must remove it from my project, but if I do so I will receive an error for SLComposeViewController because I think it is not existing in Twitter Framework, And that means I can not use both in the same project , Am I wrong ?

Comment: You must make sure Social framework is optional (Project -> Build Phases -> Libraries). Because this framework isn't available on iOS 5, also please check the updated code and also use Twitter framework for complete compatibility

Comment: If I want to add an alert view to iOS 5 to warn the user if he/she is not signing in a Twitter account and take him/her to the Setting App , what code do i need to add to make the user access the Setting App?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18123/discussion-between-daniel-and-4slices)

Comment: Hello Daniel, I need more help if you don't mind. Now I need to share photo on Facebook I searched the web and I found your sample code FB which uploading videos to Facebook , but I'm wondering how to use it to share photos and how to implement the get me and uploading methods in one button not in two. I mean when the user tap the share button will be directed to the permission and after giving my App the permission the photo will be posted on his wall automatically . Which I'm not sure it can be done or not. Thanks in advance .

Comment: @ChuckKelly I'm not sure I understand why you think that. I've provided my own sample code and quoted Apple and another SO question. What's wrong with this answer that you feel like it's horrible?

Comment: Its dependent on a library and i feel that most ppl looking this up would want code that allows them to post to twitter without the dialog this lib includes.

Comment: Maybe thats what they suggest , but SLComposeViewController is a horribly gaudy solution for any social network with any integrity to use.

Comment: Gaudy solution for social networks without integrity... Well what isn't subjective about that... I would actually put out there that the majority of your iOS users will be expecting an iOS experience, one they're familiar with. So if you disagree with that then good luck to you and your app.

Answer (score 0):

Here how i use it:

```
        NSLog(@"Ready to Tweet."); 
        TWTweetComposeViewController *tweetComposer = [[TWTweetComposeViewController alloc] init];
        [tweetComposer setInitialText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"My message"]];
        [tweetComposer addImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"114x114"]];
        [tweetComposer addURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://myPage"]];
        tweetComposer.completionHandler = ^(TWTweetComposeViewControllerResult result){
        if(result == TWTweetComposeViewControllerResultDone){
            NSLog(@"Tweeted.");

        } else if(result == TWTweetComposeViewControllerResultCancelled) {
            NSLog(@"Cancelled.");
        }

        [self.navigationController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
        };
        [self presentModalViewController:tweetComposer animated:YES];
```

Comment: Do you that I need to upload the image on a website and just post the link of it . If this what your code does so can you please till me how to attach an image which existing in my app to post on twitter ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should not use the `TWTweetComposeViewController` anymore, it is deprecated. You should use `SLComposeViewController` class. It's almost identical in usage.

Comment: You have a `UIImage` with you, in your app, the `SLComposeViewController` or `TWTweetComposeViewController` handles uploading to Twitter. However please see my answer, as you should avoid using `TWTweetComposeViewController`: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12907850/662605

Comment: I don't agree.... The problem is more complex. If you support iOS 4.3 and up (like i do) it is better to use the TWTweetComposeViewController (note that tweets will only work as from iOS5). if you only plan to use iOS 6 the SLComposeViewController is better

Answer (score 0):

if you are using ios 5.0  then you can directly post image like

Add  Framwork twitter.framework

import  Twitter/TWTweetComposeViewController.h

```
-(void)postToTwittert
{
    Class TWTweetComposeViewControllerClass = NSClassFromString(@"TWTweetComposeViewController");

    if (TWTweetComposeViewControllerClass != nil) {
        if([TWTweetComposeViewControllerClass respondsToSelector:@selector(canSendTweet)]) {
            TWTweetComposeViewController *twitter = [[TWTweetComposeViewController alloc] init];

            [twitter setInitialText:@"text"];
            [twitter addImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"imagename"]];
            [twitter addURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.com"]];

            [self presentViewController:twitter animated:YES completion:nil];

            twitter.completionHandler = ^(TWTweetComposeViewControllerResult res) {

                if(res == TWTweetComposeViewControllerResultDone)
                {
                    NSLog(@"success for twitter post");

                }
                else if(res == TWTweetComposeViewControllerResultCancelled)
                {

                    UIAlertView* alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Canceled" message:@"Your Tweet was not posted" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];

                    [alertView show];

                }

                [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];

            };
        }
    }
}
```

call this function where you wants twitter post

and do appropriate changes that you want..

Best luck..

Answer (score 0):

I just use `UIActivityViewController` to post to Twitter now.

```
UIActivityViewController *controller = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:@[@"Default Text", [UIImage imageNamed:@"imageName"]] applicationActivities:nil];

[self presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:nil];
```

This will present a controller where the user can decide what to do (Post to Twitter, Post to Facebook, etc...)

It then uses the system tweet sheet etc... to do it.

You don't have to provide the default text.  This can be overwritten anyway.

Oh, also, no frameworks required for this.